# Specific command I want in my discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bitcoin

I'm looking for a specific command code for my discord.js bot, where you can send the command and get bitcoin's price in AUD and USD. But, I can't find some code anywhere. If someone can lend me some code, I will gladly use it and give credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API: https://api.alternative.me/v2/ticker/

Using fetch in NodeJS, you would do something like this:

```js
fetch("https://api.alternative.me/v2/ticker/").then(function (r) {
    r.json().then(function (data) {
        message.channel.send(data.data[1].quotes.USD.price)
    });
});
```

This API only features USD prices, for AUD you would need to find something else. I certainly hope this won't be used for another BTC scam bot.